# wordpress query builder (typerocket) get post with relationship table data

Tags: wordpress, query-builder, typerocket

I'm trying to get some post 'wp_posts.post_type', 'servitod_plan' in this case there are only 2 plans with that post_type. these posts have associated some wp_postmeta . when I try to bring each post, with the data of its relationship with postmeta brings me duplicates. when I look at the record it brings me
one object for each wp_postmeta.meta_key

I only want to bring the posts that correspond to 'wp_posts.post_type', 'servitod_plan' and their relation wp_postmeta of key name: value in this case plan_fee: 3000, etc.

```
My Controller.


  $query = tr_query()->table('wp_posts');
        $query->setIdColumn('ID');
        $results = $query->select('wp_posts.post_name', 'wp_posts.ID', 'wp_postmeta.meta_value')
        ->join('wp_postmeta', 'wp_postmeta.post_id', '=', 'wp_posts.ID')
        ->where('wp_posts.post_type', 'servitod_plan')
        ->get();

   return $results; // for develpment and test
```

MY WP_POSTMETA TABLE

[image]

MY WP_POSTS TABLE

[image]

when i see the RETURN DATA $RESULTS

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass one more `->where('wp_posts.ID', 2271)` and you can pass post id. check the below code.

```
$query   = tr_query()->table('wp_posts');
$query->setIdColumn('ID');
$results = $query->select('wp_posts.post_name', 'wp_posts.ID', 'wp_postmeta.meta_value')
    ->join('wp_postmeta', 'wp_postmeta.post_id', '=', 'wp_posts.ID')
    ->where('wp_posts.post_type', 'servitod_plan')->whereIn('wp_posts.ID', 2271)
    ->get();
return $results; // for develpment and test
```

**Update**

for multiple ids you can use like `->whereIn('wp_posts.ID', array('2271','2269' ) )`

Comment: i have 2 post, 2 ids